# Searching for unsent messages in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I would like to clean out my deleted items folder, and I have a bunch of old drafts that I'd like to delete permenantly. I can identify them by a little icon that looks like an "edit" flag:
[image: Outlook Draft icon]

I cannot find out how to query for them. "messageclass" does not have an option for drafts.

Answer (score 5):

You'd want to create a new custom **Search Folder**, select "Deleted Items" as a source folder and specify the **Criteria** on the **Advanced** tab as follows:

```
Field: All Mail Fields -> Sent
Condition: does not exist
```

[image: Search Folder Criteria for Unsent messages]

Do not forget to click the **Add to List** button. After opening this Search Folder, you'll see all your drafts there. You can right-click this folder holding the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key and select **Delete All** to permanently remove its contents.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is that you may Sort the messages in Deleted items folder by "Icon", so that the messages with the "edit" icon will be gathered together. You can use Shift key to more easily select these messages to delete them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tried the above but unfortunately didn't work for me.

I just did this and it worked:

**Sort your emails by "From", the ones with "none" at the top will be your drafts.**

[Screenshot of how to sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRi6g.png)